# What is exactly flush in node stats?

Tags: elasticsearch

When i see the node stat of my cluster using node stats API http://:9200_nodes/stats?pretty=true

it is show flush like this:

```
"flush" : {
          "total" : 30,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 6964
        }
```

My translog flush interval is 180 minutes or 1200 mb , so i think flush should be done based on these values & i am sure that i am not reaching 1200 mb limit.

But if i keep on checking my node stats then flush values (total) are keep on increasing, so what is it means? is something else also flushing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flush also happens based on the number of operations executed. In general, you shouldn't change the default settings in ES with regards to flush, there are continuous improvements to the defaults based on the internal enhancements, so best simply stay with the default. Its quite delicate, and increasing flush (or making refresh unbounded as another example), can have confusing results, for example, to a degree where indexing slows down since the indexing thread in Lucene has to do the internal Lucene flush when it reaches its buffer limit.

Comment: can this be a cause of random response time for search queries ?